# xampp 1.8.2/3 virtual host setup = access forbidden 403 except localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

its a shame, but i have been stuck on setting up the virtual host for a few days, and im here for some help. i have set up virtual hosts before with previous versions of xampp, but xampp 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 are just about to make me pull my hair out.

osx 10.9

after uncommenting the include for httpd-vhosts.conf (in httpd.conf), localhost and everything else gets the 403 error with the exception of localhost/phpmyadmin

in my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website”
    ServerName website.com
    <Directory “/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/website”>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i have tried the following so far:
-changing the user and group in httpd.conf from daemon and daemon to myusername and admin
- in httpd.conf, i even tried

```
    <Directory />
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

but this would return a 404 error instead when i try to access localhost or any name listed in the hosts file that redirects to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

This problem also made me frustated, but finally I found working solution for this. Your config for ***httpd-vhosts.conf*** is fine but you need to add **User** and **Group** to your ***httpd.conf*** as explained clearly [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148165). For your reference below is my ***httpd.conf*** file showing lines that you need to add suitable with your local environment:

```
...
<IfModule unixd_module>
User yourOwnUserName
Group www
</IfModule>
...
```

**Remember to change user name suitable with your own.** Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

This works for me:

```
NameVirtualHost *
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "D:\host\www"
    ServerName host.local
  <Directory "D:\host\www">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change host.local to your custom name

|Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

**Top answer selected:**

Just need to change only 3 files:

1. httpd.conf from conf
2. httpd-vhost from vhost file
3. host file from windows host file

Easy steps to do. You can do by yourself. Just follow the link below:

### [**Make multiple virtual host on XAMPP**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7hsGEyMnLAhXnC5oKHaxdBKE4ChC3AggnMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKDYrkJJff3I&usg=AFQjCNHDt0jbMix3FQeeqWG3OWBZaIi14Q&sig2=kJFZa2C1wCqReWGtSyjJGA&bvm=bv.117218890,d.bGs)

Comment: This is not a clear answer, and the link could be posted in the comments too.